# Почему не продлевается время токена?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, token

Здравствуйте, есть такой код:

```
async.waterfall([
     function(done){
          User.findById(verifiedJwt.body.sub, function(err, user) {
              if (err)  return next(err);
              if (!user) return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Incorrect token credentials' });
              req.user = user;
              done(null);
          });
     }
],
function(err){
     if (err) return next(err);
     verifiedJwt.setExpiration(new Date().getTime() + (60*60*1000));
     return next();
});
```

Этот код вызывается при переходе пользователя по одному из маршрутов, и отвечает за то, что продлевает время жизни токена. Само продление жизни токена происходит тут

```
verifiedJwt.setExpiration(new Date().getTime() + (60*60*1000));
```

И если верить документации [модуля](https://github.com/jwtk/njwt), то все должно срабатывать. Но на практике это не происходит.

**UPDATE**
Переделал все под модуль [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken).

```
    jwt.verify(token, secrets.sessionSecret, function (err, verifiedJwt) {
        if (err){
            if (err.message === 'jwt expired'){
                req.user = null;
                console.log(err);
                return res.redirect('/login');
            }
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        async.waterfall([
                function(done){
                    User.findById(verifiedJwt.data, function(err, user) {
                        if (err)  return next(err);
                        if (!user) return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Incorrect token credentials' });
                        req.user = user;
                        done(null);
                    });
                }
            ],
            function(err){
                if (err) return next(err);
                console.log("before", verifiedJwt);
                verifiedJwt.exp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60*60);
                console.log("after",verifiedJwt);
                return next();
            });
    });
```

Время жизни токена меняю так:

```
    function(err){
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log("before", verifiedJwt);
        verifiedJwt.exp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60*60);
        console.log("after",verifiedJwt);
        return next();
    });
```

Но по факту оно не обновляется..

Comment: Он доходит до того места, не валится тупо в обработку ошибки? Кстати, я бы не тянул на вашем месте библиотеку версии 0.3.2 с сотней звезд, а тянул бы вот это с почти 4к звезд: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму переделал под рекомендованный модуль. Но не нашел там метода для продления жизни токена, по этому изменил его по своему. Обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста что не так)

Comment: Не знаю, я вообще по ноде постольку поскольку, просто мимо проходил) Пристальным взглядом не вижу, тут надо хорошенько отдебажиться